# MongoDB failed document validation for required fields

Tags: mongodb

I am having an issue with inserting data into mongo when sending the data via postman, I am using this schema, following the example here https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/json-schema-validation--checking-your-arrays

```
[
  {
    "create": "sample",
    "validator": {
      "$jsonSchema": {
        "bsonType": "object",
        "required": ["name", "box_size", "dyes"],
        "properties": {
          "_id": {},
          "name": {
            "bsonType": ["string"],
            "description": "'name' is a required string"
          },
          "box_size": {
            "enum": [3, 4, 6],
            "description": "'box_size' must be one of the values listed and is required"
          },
          "dyes": {
            "bsonType": ["array"],
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "items": {
              "bsonType": ["object"],
              "required": ["size", "color"],
              "additionalProperties": false,
              "description": "'items' must contain the stated fields.",
              "properties": {
                "size": {
                  "enum": ["small", "medium", "large"],
                  "description": "'size' is required and can only be one of the given enum values"
                },
                "color": {
                  "bsonType": "string",
                  "description": "'color' is a required field of type string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

If the request is made via Postman, the error below is thrown

```
"$jsonSchema\",\"schemaRulesNotSatisfied\": [{\"operatorName\": \"required\",\"specifiedAs\": {\"required\": [\"name\",\"box_size\",\"dyes\"]},\"missingProperties\": [\"box_size\",\"dyes\",\"name\"]}]}}]"
```

Postman request

```
{"name": "Rainbow RGB", "box_size": 3,
"dyes": [
        {"size": "small", "color": "red"},
        {"size": "medium", "color": "green"},
        {"size": "large", "color": "blue"}]}
```

But I can insert successfully via `mongosh`

```
db.sample.insertOne({name: "Rainbow RGB", box_size: 3,
dyes: [
        {size: "small", color: "red"},
        {size: "medium", color: "green"},
        {size: "large", color: "blue"}]})
```

Comment: you have a typo in size*s*

Comment: corrected, but I am still having the error

Comment: Show the entire POSTMAN request. **missingProperties** tells you that the data you think you are sending is not what MongoDB received.

Comment: That's the entire request, If I remove the required line, I am able to send the data successfully via POSTMAN

Comment: @Fehmy I am having the same problem, have you found the solution yet?